# Why LOG filter is returning the black background image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I had taken co-relation of image with LOG filter via imfilter command.

```
z=imfilter(I,fspecial('log',11,1.5)); 
figure
imshow(z);
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Shows us some code and some results! I wish I could understand a whole image processin gproblem with a single line :(. However, Is your image uint8 or double?

Comment: Couldn't post Images :/ because of lagging by 10 or so points, but sample code is as follows                                                    z=imfilter(I,fspecial('log',11,1.5));                                         %I is image 11 is mask size and 1.5 is sigma's value
figure,imshow(z);

Comment: Upload it somewhere and I will post the link. I will put it

Comment: try: 
z=imfilter(double(I)./255,fspecial('log',11,1.5)); 
figure
imshow(x);

Comment: http://s27.postimg.org/uedr8eopf/LOG_Filtered_Image.jpg

Comment: minor note: that would be imshow(z) right?

Comment: PLease, edit your question with the information. Additionally, I meant you to post the original image. We know how a black image is

Comment: Original Image was: http://s30.postimg.org/dg7e0fjfl/wheel.png

Comment: Yes that actually is imshow(z).

Comment: How the hell did this question get 10 upvotes? (10 upvotes / 3 downvotes = +7 total).  Do you have a bunch of sock puppet accounts to puff up your reputation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting the image to double (double precision) will resolve the issue because imread command took the image in default unit8 (unsigned int) format.

Comment: I would consider using `im2double` instead of just casting as `double` as `im2double` will also normalize the intensities so that they fit between `[0,1]`.  Just casting to `double` will not do this.  Also, `imread` loading in an image in "default" `uint8` is technically not correct.  The precision of each pixel is defined in the header of the image that `imread` parses and examines.  For example, TIF can be 8, 16 or 24 or 32 bits. It's just the majority of images out there use 8 bits per intensity / colour, so we would naturally think it's "default".

Comment: but im2double will not work in this case because the intensities will lie in [0,1] but we don't want to normalize the intensities,if we do so the resultant image will be black.I had tried that and got the accurate results.

Comment: Utter nonsense.  `imshow` for `double` type images is **designed** to take in intensities between `[0,1]`, which get **visualized** to intensities between black and white.  Whoever gave you the +1 vote for your comment doesn't know what they're talking about either.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that you are not showing the result properly.

Your result is in range 0-31, but you need to convert it to 0-255 to plot it!

do

```
imshow(mat2gray(z))
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the Result in Range 0-31?

Comment: Because you are applying a log filter and the filter does not normalize the result.

Comment: @AnderBiguri - You can also do `imshow(z, [])`, which would contrast normalize the results for display where the minimum and maximum values would map to `[0,1]`.  Otherwise, good spot!

Comment: converting the image to double from default unit8 will also resolve the issue.

Comment: @M.Zaman You need to be careful on how you're converting to double.  Simply doing `double(z)`; will not solve the problem because you will have values that are beyond 1 and will saturate the image when trying to display it.  Consider using `im2double` instead to contrast normalize the intensities to `[0,1]`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this problem is not to change your image, but to change the way `imshow` displays it. Try this:

```
>> imshow(z, [0, 31]);
```

Or, better yet, try this:

```
>> imshow(z, []);
```

which will re-scale the image automatically, mapping the minimum value to 0 and the maximum to 255.